# “poster awards” vs. “posters awards”

Tags: grammatical-number

If there are awards for more than one poster, what shall I write as a title for the posters presentation to be awarded: *Posters Awards* or *Poster Awards?*

Answer (score 1):

Poster Awards.  As a title, the plural is the thing being given, not multiple recipients.

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding the question, posters are not what is being given but for what the the awards are being given.

Answer (score 1):

*Poster award* is a regular compound noun in which the modifier (poster) is usually singular – even if a plural would be better fitting semantically. For example:

- A *book shelf* usually holds more than one book.
- *Mushroom soup* usually contains more than one mushroom.

(The predominant exception to this are words that are used only or predominantly in the plural form ([pluralia tantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum)), e.g., in *arms dealer.*)

Thus even if each single award was for multiple posters, I would still talk about a *poster award* and not a *posters award.*

Furthermore, if I am guessing correctly that this is about the poster award on a scientific conference, each award is given for a single poster, not multiple ones. There may be multiple awards (each for one poster), but this is indicated by using *award* in the plural form.